# Unable to change default launcher

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, launcher, lenovo, nova-launcher

I have Lenovo k5 smartphone with Lollipop 5.1.1.

As stock "Lenovo Launcher" sucks, I installed Nova Launcher and set it as default.

Unfortunatelly, after each restart (or even without restart, after few hours) the default launcher changes to stock "Lenovo launcher".

Is that a way to permanent change?